# Flight cancellations due to bad weather in Hong Kong and insurance for it

Tags: air-travel, insurance, cancellations, hong-kong, delays

I'm an F1 graduate student in the US. I'll be in Hong Kong in early June for about a week and I plan to return to the US one day before my visa expires.

I've been told that that period of time (early June) the weather in Hong Kong may cause some flight delays/cancellations. If my flight is delayed for more than (roughly) 30 hours, then my only option will be to go to my home country to get a new visa and then return to the US.

So I was wondering whether there are insurances which can cover this scenario? If yes, which ones are the best? (If it matters, I'll fly with United, and the return trip costs 800 USD)

Comment: The best travel insurance is to avoid traveling so close to the visa expiration date at all costs.

Comment: June is actually quite alright. Late July to early September is the typhoon season, when problems can happen. You shouldn't worry about June.

Comment: Typhoon season in Hong Kong runs roughly from June through to October but July, August and September are the months when bad weather conditions are at peak, so it will be not a problem if you are travelling in June.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't believe there is a travel insurance policy that does what you want. Many policies will offer certain coverage for trip interruption and cancellation, but the terms in the fine print are often limited. Typical coverage is to reimburse you for the unusable portion of any prepaid non-refundable expenses and extra accommodation you may need to pay for. And the limits are usually fairly low (see, for instance, [a typical Allianz policy](https://www.allianztravelinsurance.com/api/certificates/download/all?ProductID=17059&State=CA) where trip interruption coverage only pays up to $100/day for five days if you're delayed for more than 24 hours. At most, they will also pay "reasonable 
additional transportation expenses to  get  to your original destination or to a place where you can continue your trip." I would not want to try to argue that means they have to fly you home for a new visa, and I certainly wouldn't want to argue that means they need to fly you home and then to the US. You may get some coverage out of it, but likely not all your expenses.

Travel insurance policies do not not cover the extended consequences of delays, such as a visa expiring. There are many flights between Hong Kong and the US, so even with an extended delay, there are a number of flights to choose from. The best form of "insurance" would be to allow yourself an extra day just in case.

If you do run into trouble, I'd be sure the airline agent is aware of your visa situation, as they may be able to give you some preference in rebooking.

It's also possible to apply for a US visa at the [Consulate in Hong Kong](https://hk.usconsulate.gov/) if that becomes necessary.